# How can I filter all bundle child products in magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2, bundled-product, bundle, bundle-product

I'm using the MageWorx autocomplete, but it display the child products from bundles

Comment: What do you want to display?

Comment: You have display bundle product instead os child product?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get child products and parent products i have tried all and finally use this custom query to get all products parent, child.

```
$connection= $this->_resources->getConnection();
                        $select = $connection->select()
                            ->from(['o' =>  $this->_resources->getTableName('catalog_category_product')]);
                        $select->where('category_id = ?', $subcat->getId());
                        $result = $connection->fetchAll($select);

                    $productIds = array();
                    foreach ($result as $product)
                    {
                        $productIds []= $product['product_id'];
                    }
```

Here you get all product ids of specific category now create a collection factory of **\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory** and filter your products

```
    $collection = $this->CollectionFactory->create();
                        $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('in',$productIds));
```

Do what you like with the products

```
foreach ($collection as $product)
                        {
                            $productname = $product->getname();
                        }
```

If this helps accept and vote it